# Find the domain of the function $\frac{\sqrt{5-x} - \sqrt{6+x}}{\ln(x^2-1)}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I have troubles finding the domain of this function.

$$f(x) = \dfrac{\sqrt{5-x} - \sqrt{6+x}}{\ln(x^2-1)}$$

Thank you for any help.

Here is what I've done so far:

- for $\sqrt{5-x}$, $5\ge x$
- for $\sqrt{x+6}$, $x\ge -6$

Hence $-6\le x\le5$.

For the denominator:
$$x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$$
Hence $x>1$ or $x<-1$.

Comment: We would surely like to help you, but first you have at least to write down what you tried so far. I will edit the question in a readable way, but you have to do your part. We do not solve homework for free (neither for money, of course).

Comment: okay ill upload an image of what I've done so far in a few minutes

Comment: @Kleinbottle i have uploaded what ive done so far, please assist in anyway you can

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Please don't use images and type the formulas here by  MathJax. Here is a tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track.

To find a domain, in general, look for all operations in the definition of your function than can cause a problem: the argument of a square root must be $\ge0$, the argument of a log must be $>0$, the denominator of a quotient must be $\ne0$, etc. Each constraint yields some set of admissible values of $x$. The intersection of all these sets is your domain: it's the set of values of $x$ such that every operation to compute your function is well defined.

From the square roots you got $-6\le x\le5$, which is correct. You can also write this $x\in[-6,5]$.
The logarithm yields $|x|>1$, that is $x<-1$ or $x>1$, or $x\in]-\infty,-1[\,\cup\,]1,\infty[$.

The intersection of those sets is $[-6,-1[\,\cup\,]1,5]$. But you are not done yet: the denominator must not be zero, that is $x^2-1\ne1$, so the value $\sqrt2$ and $-\sqrt2$ are not admissible, and the domain is finally:

$$[-6,-\sqrt2[\,\cup\,]-\sqrt2,-1[\,\cup\,]1,\sqrt2[\,\cup\,]\sqrt2,5]$$

Comment: thank you. i understand now but i don't yet know why you equate x^2-1 to 1. I would like to learn more about that if possible

Comment: @mather The denominator is zero if the logarithm is zero, and this happens when its argument is $1$, since $\log1=0$. Hence the denominator is zero when $x^2-1=1$.

Comment: thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

These type of problems are not difficult, you just have to think about the domain of the elementary functions and what problems can derive from them. Let
$$f(x) = \dfrac{\sqrt{5-x} - \sqrt{6+x}}{\ln(x^2-1)}$$
In general $\sqrt{t}$ is defined $\forall t \geq 0$
So our first condition is:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
5-x \geq 0\\
6+x \geq0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
So we have $-6 \leq x \leq 5$
Using the same strategy of before, now we study $\ln(x^2-1)$ 
$\ln t$ id well defined $\forall t>0$ So first of all we impose $x^2-1>0$
But we note that the logarithm is in the denominator; so you also have to impose denominator $\neq0$
In formulas:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
x^2-1>0\\
\ln(x^2-1) \neq 0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Solving we obtain $x<-1 \lor x>1$ and $x\neq \pm \sqrt{2}$
After you have done all the cases, you have the solution:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
-6 \leq x \leq 5\\
x<-1 \lor x>1 \\
x\neq \pm \sqrt{2}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Finally we obtain:
$D=[-6,-\sqrt{2}[\ \cup \ ]-\sqrt{2},-1[\ \cup \ ]1,\sqrt{2}[\ \cup \ ]\sqrt{2},5] $